# American using weak conjugations for BrE strong and vice versa

Tags: american-english, british-english, past-participles, conjugation

Reading American literature of questionable quality, I often come across words like *leaped*, *kneeled* and *creeped*, and they always cause this Englishman to hesitate. Can anyone explain the usage?

I could imagine a reversion from old, exceptional usage to something regarded as the norm, but that doesn't explain the reverse phenomenon: *snuck* for *sneaked*, *dove* for *dived*, for example.

Comment: *Creeped* sounds unusual to us Americans, too (at least to me). See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=creeped%3Aeng_us_2019%2Ccrept%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccreeped%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrept%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0). And *kneeled* and *leaped* used to be moderately common in the U.K.; it's just that Americans haven't stopped using them. Again, [see Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leaped%2Cleapt%2Ckneeled%2Cknelt&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=29&smoothing=10).

Comment: (and I wouldn't be surprised if American literature of the best quality contained the past tenses *leaped* and *kneeled*. Pat Conroy, [for example](https://www.google.com/books/edition/South_of_Broad/78X5CB4Z91wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=leaped).)

Comment: *_That movie really crept me out._ Reified verbs get regularized.

Comment: The implication is that there is no British literature of questionable quality. Harumph. What is questionable quality anyway? Try Finnegan's Wake, a page a day. https://lithub.com/finnegans-wake-at-80-in-defense-of-the-difficult/

Answer (score 6):

This article from [GSBE](https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar--ed--and--t-ending-verbs.html) (adjusted & reformatted) looks sound/authoritative if annoyingly inconclusive in its recommendations:

> **Morphology: -ed- and -t-Ending Verbs**
>  
> Most regular verbs take -d or -ed endings in the past tense (climbed, rushed, smoked, touched, washed) while some have
> retained their older -t endings (built, felt, lent, meant, spent).
> But a few troublemakers have alternative -ed and -t endings –
>
> - burned, burnt
> - dreamed, dreamt
> - kneeled, knelt
> - leaped, leapt
> - leaned, leant
> - learned, learnt
>    - smelled, smelt
> - [speeded, sped] (a related class)
> - spelled, spelt
> - spilled, spilt
> - spoiled, spoilt
>
> and their rules of use are unfortunately inconsistent.
>
> **Firstly**, there is a general American preference for -ed endings and a British preference for -t endings, The Times, for example,
> choosing -t endings.[¹]
>
> **Secondly**, *some* authorities give -ed endings as the past tense (I burned the toast) and -t endings as the past participle (I have burnt
> the toast), but none declares the reverse usage to be incorrect.
>
> To muddy the waters further, a **third**
> convention requires -ed endings when the duration of the action is
> important, and -t endings when it is not. In other words, we
> use -ed endings to imply ‘action going on’, [progressive aspect,]
> and -t endings to imply ‘action completed’ [perfective aspect] –
>
> - The fire burned for days                                  (Duration important; action going on)
> - Carol burnt her finger on the stove                 (Duration unimportant; action completed)
> - I dreamed of her all night                                (Duration important)
> - I dreamt of her last night          (Duration unimportant; length of the dream is irrelevant)
> - James always spelled liaise with only one I              (Duration important)
> - James mistakenly spelt liaise with only one I          (Duration unimportant; it is of no consequence how long it took James to write
>   the word)
> - It took me a long time before I learned to use the keyboard        (Duration important)
> - Both James and Carol learnt from their mistakes                        (Duration unimportant)
> - [Jill speeded up and sped up the hill (the latter having a deducible endpoint)]
>
> *In the circumstances, therefore, it matters little which ending we*
> *choose[, provided we are not inconsistent with multiple examples]. We*
> *can follow [any] of the ‘rules’ or simply opt for one ending on all*
> *occasions.*
>
> **When used as adjectives, however, the spellings are fixed** –
>
> - burnt toast
> - spilt milk
> - spoilt child
> - learned person
>
> ____ ¹ The Times Style Guide. No longer available online. Multiple access, 2003–04.

Answer (score 1):

I learned/learnt the difference between British English and American English while at school. I was used to using British English though I knew American English. Now I am trying to apply some American English words - program, center, apartment, bill (note), check (cheque) etc.

I always put emphasis on the difference between 'gone' and 'been' in British English, not in American English.

// British English uses - ending while American English prefers - form.

British English- burnt. learnt, spelt, knelt, dreamt, spoilt, leapt

American English- burned, learned, kneeled, spelled, dreamed, spoiled, leaped

They are equally important to me.//

(present) creep- (past) crept - (past participle) crept- I am not familiar with 'creeped'.

I have learnt 'dived' as the past form and the past participle form of 'dive'. In this case I normally use 'dived', not 'dove'. I use 'dove' as a noun meaning 'a bird'. But I know that 'dove' is used as the past form.

Collins English Dictionary-

' LANGUAGE NOTE:
American English sometimes uses the form dove, pronounced (doʊv), for the past tense.'

I want to say that language is changing. We can accept new things.

Comment: So you're saying that American English is more conservative (maintains older forms) than British English? How then do you explain the OPs question about 'dived' and 'dove '-  'dived' is the historical form, used by BrE, but in recent AmE the tendency is to use a -new- form 'dove' which sounds traditional (because it is a 'strong' form) but is an entirely new invention (it never existed in English til now).

Comment: To me,  both British English and American English are correct and they are equally important.

Comment: No doubt, but that's not the question. the question is about why the two differ, one conservative in one case and different from the source (early modern English) in the second (what about 'dived/dove')

Comment: @MohammadFarukhAhmad Your answer looks like a quote. Please prefix quoted material with `>` and [reference it correctly](/help/referencing), at least with a link.

Comment: It's not just a matter of being more conservative, but of English historically having multiple forms, and sometimes one predominates in the UK and the other in the US. Particularly in the days before mass media, there was a lot of regional variation in language.